# How to Download table JSP to txt

Tags: javascript, jsp

its what i'v try

```
userDetails='';
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
  var detail='(';
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    detail+=$(this).html()+',';
  });
  detail=detail.substring(0,detail.length-1);
  detail+=')';
 userDetails+=detail+"\r\n";
});
var a=document.getElementById('save');
a.onclick=function(){
    var a = document.getElementById("save");
    var file = new Blob([userDetails], {type: 'text/plain'});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = "data.txt";
}
```

It goes well but, my last `<td>` is button, how to delete last `<td>` of my table ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jquery in your example, you could use:

```
$('table tr').each(function (){
  $(this).find('td:last').remove();
})
```

It removed the last `<td>` in a table row. Make sure to scope your table using a id or class, because this script applies to all tables on your page.

Comment: how to put id on this function ? so i can remove the Specific table

Comment: Rather use: `$('table#mySpecificTable tr')` and `<table id="mySpecificTable">` to scope your javascript